# Mavericks: Safari does not login in into web services

Tags: macos, login, safari, password-management, auto-form-fill

Since when I upgraded ML to Mavericks Safari is no longer able to log me into Facebook. When I go to the login page it suggests me the correct credentials, I hit the Login button, the page refreshes but nothing happens, like if the credentials where empty.
Firefox works perfectly, I even logged out and back in to make sure the credentials are the same that Safari suggests, and so they are.
Needless to say for a different user on the same Mavericks Safari logs in correctly.

The same happens with most web pages that need a login, web mails for instances, I have tow accounts on different webmail providers and none of them works. Of course using the same mail services with POP3 works fine.
Even on this very site I cannot post a thing with Safari, I'm going to switch to Firefox to be able to post this question.
Again, Firefox or a different user are OK.

Do you have any idea/suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance I would go into Safari preferences (command+,) and go to the Passwords tab and Remove All and uncheck autofilling of usernames and passwords

Then in the privacy tab Remove All Website Data.

This should reset Safari and allow you to log into sites again.

[image: Privacy preferences]